Does this theorem hold under specific conditions and not in general?
In baby rudin, Thm 2.34, states:

Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed.

The proof goes as :

Proof Let $K$ be a compact subset of a metric space $X$. We shall prove
that the complement of $K$ is an open subset of $X$.
Suppose $p \in X,\ p \notin K$. If $q \in K$, let $V_q$ and $W_q$ be neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$, respectively, of radius less than $\frac{1}{2}d(p, q)$ [see Definition 2.18(a)].
Since $K$ is compact, there are finitely many points $q_1,\dots , q_n$ in $K$ such that
$K \subseteq W_{q_1} \cup \dots \cup W_{q_n} = W.$ If $V = V_{q_1} \cap \dots \cap V_{q_n}$, then $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$ which does not
intersect W. Hence $V \subset K^c$, so that $p$ is an interior point of $K^c$. The
theorem follows.

My question here is that, isn't the argument: "Hence $ V \subset K^c$." true under the assumption that $p$ is itself an interior point of $X$. Infact the conclusion that "$p$ is an interior point of $K^c$" itself implies that $p$ is an interior point of $X$ since $X\supset K^c$.
So, this theorem only holds when all points of $X$ are interior points, i.e. $X$ is an open set and not for situation where $X$ contains finitely many isolated points.
Am I right? Or my reasoning is lacking some logic/is wrong?

"$X$ is open" does not make sense. Open in where? $X$ is always open in itself. And check the definition of "$p$ is an interior point of $K^c$" more carefully, you'll find that it includes the case of $p$ being an isolated point just fine.

@QiaochuYuan I meant that when $X$ is an open set. Also, isn't isolated point different from interior point, where isolated points are points which are not limit points and every interior point is a limit point, right?

Open in what? Write down a precise definition and you should find that every metric space satisfies it. And again, there is no reason "$p$ is an interior point of $K^c$" should imply that $p$ cannot be isolated, just check the definitions. Work through the definitions for $X$ a finite metric space (where every subset is both compact and closed).

The set $\ X\ $ is the entire metric space.  If $\ \tau\ $ is its topology, then by definition, $\ X\in\tau\ $—that is, $\ X\ $ must be open and every one of its points must be an interior point.  It's simply not true that such points must be limit points.
